# Make AWS AMI public by fog

Tags: amazon-web-services, fog

I am using fog to create an ami from running instance:

```
@fog = Fog::Compute.new(
        :provider => 'AWS',
        :region => 'us-west-2',
        :aws_access_key_id => aws_access_key,
        :aws_secret_access_key => aws_secret_key
    )
@fog.create_image(instance.identity,image_name,image_description)
```

Can I use fog to make this ami public?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The ami creates normally, but it's private by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found how to do it, I need to add one line to the code above:

```
@fog.modify_image_attribute(image_id,{'Add.Group' => ['all']}
```

If the image has status 'pending' (like in my case), it will throw an exception, so the final modification is:

```
@fog = Fog::Compute.new(
        :provider => 'AWS',
        :region => 'us-west-2',
        :aws_access_key_id => aws_access_key,
        :aws_secret_access_key => aws_secret_key
    )
data = @fog.create_image(instance.identity,image_name,image_description)

image_id = data.body['imageId']

print 'Waiting ami to come up'

begin
  @fog.modify_image_attribute(image_id,{'Add.Group' => ['all']})
rescue
  print(".")
  sleep(10)
  retry
end

puts 'READY!'
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the fog syntax, but to make your AMI image public, then you would use the `ec2:ModifyImageAttribute` action on your AMI image.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyImageAttribute.html

In this case, you would specify your AMI image ID along with adding a "Launch Permission" to the "all" group.

The documentation for `modify-image-attribute` in the AWS CLI has an example of setting an AMI image public:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-image-attribute.html

```
aws ec2 modify-image-attribute --image-id ami-5731123e 
  --launch-permission "{\"Add\": [{\"Group\":\"all\"}]}"
```